# Завершение программы после выполнения условия - Java

Tags: java

Я написал код(крестики нолики). В нем содержится функция которая проверяет выполнено ли условие для победы для игроков.Если да, то выводит сообщение "Игрок X победил", однако потом программа просит дальше ввести позицию, то есть продолжает игру. Я хочу чтобы программа завершалась на этом моменте.

```
for(List l: gewinner){
        if(plaeyer1position.containsAll(l)){
            return "Player 1 wins";
        } else if (plaeyer2position.containsAll(l)) {
            return "Player 2 wins";
        }
        else if(plaeyer1position.size()+plaeyer2position.size()==9){
            return "CAT.\n";
        }
```

Comment: игра может завершиться на 5 ходу, у вас почемуто сравнение идет с цифрой 9.
Не правильно определяете кто победил

Comment: На этом сайте эти крестики нолики только на одним разделе java каждую неделю проскакивают.  Приставте сколько их всего на ru сегменте, а на англоязычном? Миллион, вбейте в поисковик крестики нолики и изучите , полюбому найдёте решение

Comment: пишите `throw` и делов с концом. А если серьёзно - гуглите

Comment: эта функция игру не продолжает. Поэтому непонятно какой помощи вы ждете. Смотрите там, где идет запрос и в том месте исправляйте код. Эта функция тут вообще ни на что не влияет, непонятно, зачем она вообще в вопросе.

Answer (score -1):

Программу можно завершить если заменить `return` на `System.out.println("Игрок Х выиграл"); System.exit(0);`

Comment: этот способ примерно такой же как если для закрытия ворда или экселя выдергивать шнур из розетки. Ну а че, ворд же тоже закрылся :D Заменить, кстати, вряд ли получится, потому что если у вас функция должна возвращать строку, она и должна возвращать строку.

Comment: @Эникейщик, не совсем понимаю. Я же хотел, чтобы программа завершалась на том, что решение нашлось. Мне немного непонятна аналогия с выдергиванием шнура в данном конексте, если я изначально этого и хотел. Это же консольное приложение. Однако я бы очень хотел увидеть более элегенатное решение, вместо советов по типу "загуглите", как от коллег выше.

Comment: прочитайте мой комментарий к вопросу, вам код нужно править не в этой функции. Игру продолжает не она, не в ней и исправлять.

Comment: Смысл был в том, что после того как данная функция выполняется игра должна завершаться, так как игрок выиграл и больше в игре делать нечего. Я понимаю, что это не эта функция продолжает программу. Но вопрос был в том, чтобы после того, как функция выведет сообщение с победой она закрывала приложение. Сделать это можно только в этой функции. Наверное, я изначально не совсем правильно сформулировал суть вопроса, извините.

Comment: Начнем с того, что **выводит** сообщение совсем не эта функция. Сообщение выводится в том месте, откуда откуда эта функция вызывается. И там и надо прекращать вашу программу. "_Сделать это можно только в этой функции_" - это конечно же полная чепуха.